# Regular expression in Java detect string with single backslash

Tags: java, expression

I'm studying regular expression and I have a problem. I need a regex to detect error strings. A right string can't contains single backslash(\) but can contains double backslash(\\), can contains (\t, \r, \f, \b, ...)
Example: The regex must match this string
    'This is error string \

Comment: what is your question? my question is what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For match correct string, try this:

```
^((\\[tbnrt'"\\])|(\\u\d{4})|[^\\])+$
```

In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of `Pattern` for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern MY_PATTERN = 
              Pattern.compile("^((\\\\[tbnrt'\"\\\\])|(\\\\u\\d{4})|[^\\\\])+$");
```

And use the constant:

```
MY_PATTERN.matcher(testString).matches(); // true if don't have errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape properly.  Use `\\\\` to match `\\`.